# Can a logarithm function with two variable be expressed as a Meijer-G function?

Tags: special-functions

Let {x},{y}>0 and {a},{b}>0. can the function
log(1+ax+by)
be expressed as a Meijer-G function?

Comment: Have you looked at `MeijerGReduce`?

Comment: Yes.  Please look here:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html.  In the first 'special case' listed, let $z=ax+by$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not worked with Mathematica so far. Can not be converted using MATLAB?

Comment: MATLAB questions are not on-topic for this site.

Comment: Actually, i want to solve $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\ln (1+{{a}_{1}}x+{{a}_{2}}y)G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( {{a}_{2}}x\left| \begin{matrix}
   -{{a}_{3}}  \\
   {{a}_{4}}-1  \\
\end{matrix} \right. \right)G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( {{b}_{2}}y\left| \begin{matrix}
   -{{b}_{3}}  \\
   {{b}_{4}}-1  \\
\end{matrix} \right. \right)}}dxdy$

as a close-form expression.

Comment: I use mjw's comment and I can rewrite it as $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{G_{2,2}^{1,2}\left( {{a}_{1}}x+{{b}_{1}}y\left| \begin{matrix}
   1,1  \\
   1,0  \\
\end{matrix} \right. \right)G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( {{a}_{2}}x\left| \begin{matrix}
   -{{a}_{3}}  \\
   {{a}_{4}}-1  \\
\end{matrix} \right. \right)G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( {{b}_{2}}y\left| \begin{matrix}
   -{{b}_{3}}  \\
   {{b}_{4}}-1  \\
\end{matrix} \right. \right)}}dxdy$ 
Is there any solution for this integral?

Comment: There is a MATLAB version of the Meijer-G function:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/meijerg.html.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answers. Have you got an idea to solve the integral above?

Comment: Please look up `MeijerGReduce` as suggested, and also `Integrate`.  Make an attempt at writing your expression in *Mathematica*.  I am pretty sure that with this effort, you will have a few people at this site giving valuable help!

Comment: `f = ...; Integrate[f, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}];`

Comment: Why did you not ask about that integral to begin with in your question? Edit your post to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to be *an outline of an answer*.  The details of arguments for the Meijer-G functions still need to be filled in:

```
z[x_, y_] = a1 x + b2 y;
\[Alpha] = Evaluate@MeijerGReduce[Log[1 + z[x, y]], z[x, y]];
\[Beta] = MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}, a2 x];
\[Gamma] = MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}, b2 y];
f = \[Alpha] \[Beta] \[Gamma];
Integrate[f, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```